# Computing summary statistics individually from values in each cell in a data frame in a list

Tags: r

I have 25 data frames in the form of a list like this(three shown here, three is sufficient for sample calculations):

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2,4), c(4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2))
df2 <- data.frame(c(4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6), c(6, 3, 2, 6, 2, 6, 3))
df3 <- data.frame(c(1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2,4), c(4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2))
list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I want to make another data frame which contains the average value in each cell, and next to that I want the standard deviation. So it will be a 4 column by 7 row data frame which contains mean and standard deviation of each cell in the data frame.

How can this be done? My data also has way more than 7 rows.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the desired output for this input so that possible solutions can be verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist <- list(df1, df2, df3)
do.call(cbind, lapply(lapply(1:2, function(i) sapply(mylist, function(x) x[,i])),
                      function(a) t(apply(a, 1, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))))))
#         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 2.000000 1.7320508 4.666667 1.1547005
#[2,] 2.666667 0.5773503 4.333333 1.1547005
#[3,] 3.000000 1.7320508 2.000000 0.0000000
#[4,] 3.333333 1.1547005 5.333333 0.5773503
#[5,] 3.000000 1.7320508 4.666667 2.3094011
#[6,] 2.000000 0.0000000 4.000000 1.7320508
#[7,] 4.666667 1.1547005 2.333333 0.5773503
```

Answer (score 2):

I admit I am fair impressed by d.b's answer, but I think this problem might be better managed by turning your list into a 3d array.

```
library(abind)

a <- abind(mylist, along = 3)
a <- apply(a, c(1,2), function(i) abind(c(mean(i), sd(i)), along = 2))

data.frame(t(rbind(a[, , 1], a[, , 2])))
```

**Result**

```
      X1        X2       X3        X4
2.000000 1.5491933 4.666667 1.0327956
2.666667 0.5163978 4.333333 1.0327956
3.000000 1.5491933 2.000000 0.0000000
3.333333 1.0327956 5.333333 0.5163978
3.000000 1.5491933 4.666667 2.0655911
2.000000 0.0000000 4.000000 1.5491933
4.666667 1.0327956 2.333333 0.5163978
```